# Best way to load a notification image?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

What is the best way to load a notification image?

Here's my current way: As you can see the image loads synchronously and thus the notification can be delayed. This is a *bad* way.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/picture?type=large");

// CONSTRUCT THE NOTIFICATION DETAILS
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setContentTitle("Some Title");
builder.setContentText("Some Content Text");
builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

I really need an answer to continue working on my project.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a programming competition. We require questions to have one, specific, verifiable answer. Asking for "the best" will not work. You need to narrow down precisely what you mean by "best". What are your requirements? What constraints do you have? Describe the solution you are looking for, and then someone can provide it.

Answer (score 4):

You should first notify your Notification with no image or place holder, then load your bitmap with an AsyncTask, or use Picasso and Target callback.

Give to your task the builder that you used for the first notify, when bitmap is loaded, add it to the builder, and then re-notify your Notification.

If there's a risk that content had changed before complete image loading, store a variable that identify your current content to show, that you can check before renotify.

You can follow that exemple of MediaNotificationManager provide by google [UniversalMusicPlayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/MediaNotificationManager.java) project.

In your case :

```
// CONSTRUCT THE NOTIFICATION DETAILS
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setContentTitle("Some Title");
builder.setContentText("Some Content Text");
//builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap); // replace this line with place holder drawable from resources
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

currentLoadImageTask = new LoadImageTask(manager, builder);
currentLoadImageTask.execute("https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/picture?type=large");

// ...

static class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    final NotificationManager manager;
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public LoadImageTask(final NotificationManager manager, final NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.builder = builder;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(final String... strings) {
        if (strings == null || strings.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            final InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null || manager == null || builder == null) {
            return;
        }
        builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
}
```

With picasso :

```
// CONSTRUCT THE NOTIFICATION DETAILS
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder.setContentTitle("Some Title");
builder.setContentText("Some Content Text");
//builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap); // replace this line with place holder drawable from resources
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

// ...

Picasso.with(context)
    .load("https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/picture?type=large")
    .resize(250, 250)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, final Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
            manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
             // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
             // Do nothing
        }
    });
```

If not in UiThread you can create a Runnable and execute it in Looper

```
 final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
 uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           // Call from here
      }
 });
```

Picasso is much better simply because using cache.

And I highly recommend you to resize every bitmap you set in notification because it can easily provoc OutOfMemoryException if you dont.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I've been looking for. But, are you sure this is the correct way to use Picasso?

Comment: That's not the "classic" way where your reference directly your imageView through into() method, but in your case you have to get the Bitmap result of loading because notification manager not let you access to the imageview. And using Target is how you can get async bitmap load result with picasso. http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-com.squareup.picasso.Target-

Comment: I get error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.`  at this line `.into(new Target() {`

Comment: yes it have to, or you can specify an executor.

Comment: How can I fix this error?

Comment: I'm trying to load the image from inside `OnMessageReceived`. See method here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

Comment: There's many ways, I add one of them in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Remember,if you are loading something using the web, you have to wait a bit.
There are several solutions:

1. Load an image from the web like in your example and show.
2. Show a stub image and show downloaded image later by updating the notification
3. Use a little that helps top cache web inches. For instance, picaso

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

use `Picasso` lib to load image from url like

```
 Picasso.with(this.load(imageUri).into(imageview_id);
```